# iOS can't visit the app group folder with FileManager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sandbox, ios-app-group

I use the following code to write a png file to the App Group folder to share between my share extention and App , and i found that the write to file can be succeed (i can find the file in my terminal) , but after the writing , I use the contentsOfDirectory to get the contents of App Group Folder ,it will failed and throw

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “435D6129-B964-46A4-A066-47133EFF832D” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
```

[image]

because I can write to the App group , so I think the configuration of App Group is OK , but why I can't use contentsOfDirectory to get the contents of the App group directory?

Comment: Check if your url has `file://`, if it does, it is not a valid path

Comment: ...and to fix that, you should use `.path` rather than `.absoluteString`

Comment: @jtbandes ,thanks! that's the exactly problem!

Answer (score 4):

Using `URL.absoluteString` will return an invalid path because it contains the file scheme `file://`.

You should use URL.path, in your case it would be:

```swift
let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: groupURL.path)
```

Comment: @ximmyxiao or simply use the `func contentsOfDirectory(at url: URL, includingPropertiesForKey:, options:)` method in your case:  `FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: groupURL)`